# Detect which layout is in use in an activity with two layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I have an activity called MainActivity  that has two layouts.The previous activity has two buttons to choose which layout to be set.I need the button in MainActivity  to act differently according to the layout in use, This is my code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

        Button shoot;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
         int btnNumber = extras.getInt("button");
         switch(btnNumber) 
         {
           case 1 : setContentView(R.layout.first_layout); break;
           case 2 : setContentView(R.layout.second_layout); break;
         }
      }


      shoot=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        shoot.setOnClickListener(this);


        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch(arg0.getId()) {


        case R.id.button1:


                    // WHAT SHOULD THE CODE BE HERE

                    break;

    }


}
```

Comment: The code you post is the code for System activity?  If so, **WHAT SHOULD THE CODE BE HERE** should be what you want to do with that button.

Comment: You may want to split "System" into two Activities and completely remove ugly conditional statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your code to have one private variable at the top

```
private int whichLayout = 0;
```

Then when you get the bundle do this:

```
     switch(btnNumber) 
     {
       case 1 : setContentView(R.layout.first_layout); whichLayout = 1; break;
       case 2 : setContentView(R.layout.second_layout); whichLayout = 2; break;
       default: //Handle this
     }
```

Finally edit your onClick listener like this:

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {

    switch(whichLayout) {
    case 1: {//Do what you want; } break;
    case 2: {//Do what you want; } break;
    default: //Handle this
}
```

Comment: for what is the default ??

Comment: The default case, for instance if btnNumber was not set to 1 or 2 then you would go to the default case. It is good practice to handle the general case if something goes not as expected. 

If my answer helped then you should mark it as answered.